# Qt textBrowser string display with checkbox overwrite problem

Tags: qt, qt5

[image]

when i check other box display to textbrowser first string disappear and second string displayed. How can I print without losing each other?

Comment: Please show source code as text, not an image.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use `void QTextEdit::append(const QString &text)` (from base class `QTextEdit`, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html#append) instead of `void QTextEdit::setText(const QString &text)`.